# iOS 8 Xcode 6.1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) only on bundled app

Tags: ios, xcode

My app was working fine until I upgraded to OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) and Xcode 6.1. Now whenever I bundle my app for distribution I get a sigtrap at a specific spot in the app. This doesn't happen in the simulator or if I load the app directly onto my phone. Below is the log, I can see the line it seems to breaking on but can't figure out why it breaks there.

```
Incident Identifier: B03E6F56-B1ED-4331-B353-1B250411BA06
CrashReporter Key:   f97ffd432e0b028c9ccb3c3e953e5e656f1bdbfc
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             Role [1537]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1F18530F-7EA4-4C1E-BA52-245A8C949AE1/Role.app/Role
Identifier:          com.thesoapcollective.Role
Version:             0.4.2 (0.4.2)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-26 14:21:44.412 -0700
Launch Time:         2014-10-26 14:21:18.577 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Role                            0x001555b4 Role.TraitTracker.__allocating_init (Role.TraitTracker.Type)(trait : Role.Trait) -> Role.TraitTracker (TraitTracker.swift:0)
1   Role                            0x000b0c2c Role.Roll.__allocating_init (Role.Roll.Type)(trait : Role.Trait) -> Role.Roll (Roll.swift:0)
2   Role                            0x001b7eb8 Role.TurnTracker.__allocating_init (Role.TurnTracker.Type)(character : Role.Character, traits : [Role.Trait], difficulty : Role.Difficulty?) -> Role.TurnTracker (TurnTracker.swift:0)
3   Role                            0x0007e920 @objc Role.PlayGameCharacterViewController.prepareForSegue (Role.PlayGameCharacterViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.AnyObject?) -> () (PlayGameCharacterViewController.swift:520)
4   UIKit                           0x2efc2cbe -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 162
5   UIKit                           0x2ea9dc26 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                           0x2ea9dbcc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
7   UIKit                           0x2ea8885e -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
8   UIKit                           0x2ea9d638 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
9   UIKit                           0x2ea62428 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10264
10  UIKit                           0x2ea972ec -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 780
11  UIKit                           0x2ea96bc8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 520
12  UIKit                           0x2ea6d3d8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
13  UIKit                           0x2ece0c24 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13884
14  UIKit                           0x2ea6be34 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1292
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2b574374 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2b573782 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2b571de8 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2b4c020c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2b4c001e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  GraphicsServices                0x328b90a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
21  UIKit                           0x2eacc1cc UIApplicationMain + 1436
22  Role                            0x00143a9c main (AppDelegate.swift:0)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x392d8aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938b2a0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x392c49fc _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x392ba20e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3939f9cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39419ea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39419b80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3939f9cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39419ea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39419b80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938b4f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3938b2e4 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2b573936 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2b571edc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b4c020c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b508e76 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2bdc2eda 0x2bd83000 + 261850
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3941be90 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3941be02 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39419b8c thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x0000000c      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x14dd97e0    r5: 0x14df9db0      r6: 0x00204388      r7: 0x00348ad4
    r8: 0x14e277a0    r9: 0x152971e8     r10: 0x14e277a0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x2b2d2fe9    sp: 0x00348ac8      lr: 0x001555b4      pc: 0x001555b4
  cpsr: 0x20000010
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app with Xcode on the phone compiled for release?

Comment: I've just been running it in development mode right on my phone or I compile it for Ad Hoc distribution (which is the one crashing right now).

Comment: Try running in Xcode on the device compiled in release mode. Then you can debug it easily. In Schemes change the  Run to Release.

Comment: Ahh ok, figured it out. In the newest Xcode need to create a new Scheme then edit it and change Build Configuration to Release. I can reproduce the error through Xcode and building to my phone. Hopefully can track it down now, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on a release build ans iOS 7. #GroupHug

Comment: @hirsch did you ever squash your bug?

Comment: @mklbtz yes I did! I forget exactly what it was, but it was some weird syntax error, such as a type mismatch, that was only being caught when the app was compiled for production.