# App crashing during OTA and AD HOC distribution

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

when testing and launching my app from Xcode to Simulator or iOS device (Xcode 7) everything work fine but crashing in TestFlight and ADHOC distribution.
Im not very familiar with debugging device log but I got this execption:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000e7a44
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.995150     CFNetwork                  0x00000001839f9990 TCP Conn 0x15d954ef0 starting SSL negotiation
0.995571     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9bf18 TCP Conn 0x15d954ef0 complete. fd: 26, err: 0
0.996564     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9d444 TCP Conn 0x15d954ef0 event 1. err: 0
1.092911     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9d51c TCP Conn 0x15d954ef0 started
62.980202    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e76a88 [0x15d192400] Releasing session
62.992772    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e7626c [0x15c920800] Created session



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SimPlan                         0x00000001000e7a44 __hidden#11030_ (__hidden#11347_:123)
1   UIKit                           0x00000001888231b8 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 228
2   UIKit                           0x00000001888f36d4 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188823080 -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 100
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188823604 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 700
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188833a80 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 448
6   UIKit                           0x000000018881d70c __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 152
7   UIKit                           0x000000018881d394 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 712
8   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db77ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
9   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db7618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
10  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db79c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833cd09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ccb30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ca830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832f4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
15  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184bdc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
16  UIKit                           0x00000001885de088 UIApplicationMain + 204
17  SimPlan                         0x00000001000e5ce4 main (__hidden#11347_:21)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182e928b8 start + 4
```

I look after this post :  [Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578291/ios-8-xcode-6-1-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-only-on-bundled-app)

but I didnt succedeed in debugging my release version,
How can I debug a installed (ADHOC or testFlight ) versions in XCODE?
or maybe someone is familiar with this kind of error?

any help whatsoever would be great.
Thanks.